# How to call an android XML layout from html onclick button function?

Tags: javascript, android, html

I am developing a hybrid app that binds with HTML and android(XML). I need to call an XML layout from an html button on click function. I have tried several examples but nothing seems to work. Is there any other possible way? thanks in advance.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ScrollView 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <WebView android:id="@+id/web_view"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <LinearLayout 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <TextView 
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Order Details"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textSize="18dip"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"/>

              <Button 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/start_transaction"
                android:text="@string/start_transaction"
                android:onClick="onStartTransaction"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="16dip"
                android:layout_marginTop="10dip"/>

        </LinearLayout>    

    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: do you want to show new activity when you click on the button in HTML inWebView?

Comment: Yes...android XML Layout@VladMatvienko

Comment: Ok, then there are 2 separate problems. 1. react on button click in HTML. 2. start activity. What is the one you can't fix?

Comment: i can't bind both,when i click HTML Button it needs to show Android layout(XML)@VladMatvienko

Comment: ok, firtly you should understand that you can't directly show the `layout XML`. You need to inflate it to a view, or set a a content of new activity. Do you want to show a *new screen*?

Comment: Yes, we Need to show a new screen, when user Click Button(HTML),it is Possible To bind????@VladMatvienko

Comment: yes, it is posible. So you need to start a new activity. Are you able to edit the HTML code of the button you want to click?

Comment: Yes, can u please explain How to call an new android activity from HTML  ??? @VladMatvienko

Comment: As I said, there are 2 separate tasks: 1. start new activity. Do you know how to start new activity from android code? 2. run some android code on HTML button click.I understood that you don't know how to do this.

Comment: we have already created a new activity...the problem is we cannot able to call the created activity from HTML button click???how can i do this???

Comment: we  already created a new activity...!!!@VladMatvienko